# How can I get the Google Maps API to show the "Map"/"Satellite" buttons?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add map type controls to your map by doing:

```
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the setUIToDefault function:

```
map.setUIToDefault();
```